# IIS adding a string of characters in the url

Tags: iis

forcing IIS to https and there is a wierd string being added
to my url which i want to remove. This is on a IIS server running asp pages.
 what is this and how do i remove this string of text. (S(otldqkt4kovwlvjcdnv0xdj5))

```
url:
https://domainname.com/directory/(S(otldqkt4kovwlvjcdnv0xdj5))/login.aspx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your web server is placing the session state into the querystring.  If you do not want this to happen use the following code.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```